# What connectors do USB 3.0 devices use?

Tags: usb, usb-3, enclosures

[This USB 3.0 HDD case](http://www.amazon.de/dp/B00DW374W4/) has something that looks like a USB A receptacle requiring an A-A cable, something quite unusual.

[image]

[The only alternative](http://www.amazon.de/dp/B00EEDF1Z8) that Amazon.de is offering, has the 10-pin USB 3.0 Mini-B connector, something very rare as well.

[image]

I don’t want to end up having to have a specific cable for each device, so I’m wondering if this is normal for USB 3.0 devices. What kind of cables should I stock?

Comment: I've got a hard drive that uses that cable. I think you can use a normal A cable, BUT you fallback to USB2.0 speeds.

Comment: @RichHomolka Did you consider an USB-A to USB-A cable "normal" before the introduction of USB 3.0?

Comment: @AndreKR I've seen other A to A cables before... they're certainly rare and non-standard.

Comment: In fact previously I had overlooked [this one](http://www.amazon.de/dp/B00K4V9QW8) that indeed has the normal Micro-B. I found it only when I - inspired by your answer - searched for Micro-B explicitely.

Comment: A-A is used because Micro-USB 3.0 is fragile and doesn’t feel like it’s connected properly. USB 3.0 B is too bulky. Also, there are [*tons* of other enclosures](http://geizhals.at/de/?cat=gehhd&xf=840_USB+3.0~339_2.5%22~696_SATA+6Gb%2Fs#xf_top) available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don’t want to end up having to have a specific cable for each
>   device, so I'm wondering if this is normal for USB 3.0 devices. What
>   kind of cables should I stock?

So the links to products you provided definitely only show USB A connectors on both ends which is definitely unusual. I have numerous USB 3.0 drives and the all have an A connector on one end and a B connector on the other end. But USB 3.0 cables are definitely not like a standard USB 1.0 or 2.0 cable. So if your goal is to avoid carrying specific cables for specific devices, you will still have to make sure you have a USB 3.0 cable of some sort since there are 5 additional connections that need to be made for a USB 3.0 connection.

These images from Wikipedia show exactly what the pinouts are on the connector; 1-4 are basically USB 1.0/2.0 equivalents, but 5-9 are where the USB 3.0 magic happens. So in general USB 3.0 cables are completely different beasts from USB 1.0/2.0. Whichever way you look at it, you’re going to have to add at least 2 more cables anyway to the stuff you carry around if you want to make sure that all bases are covered.

Here is a USB A connector:

[image]

And in my experience, more and more USB 3.0 devices are using the USB 3.0 Micro-B variant; note the extra connections right next to the standard micro USB connection:

[image]

But a USB 3.0 standard B spec exists and it looks like this; note the extra connections on top of the standard micro USB connection:

[image]

Comment: You might want to put the paragraph "And in my experience..." at the top or make it bold, because that is the actual answer.